# How to disable Javascript redirect on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a Javascript redirect to redirect visitors after X seconds. However, there is also a link on the page that takes the visitor to the same page. I would like to stop the redirection if the visitors clicks on the link first.

Please note that ,the link is opening in the new window when clicked but the javascript redirect opens in the same window.

This is the code am using in my HTML Page ,

Javascript redirect code:

```
<script>
<!-- 
timeout = '5000'; // milliseconds/1000th of a sec
window.onload = setTimeout(myRedirect, timeout); // ensure we load the whole page

function myRedirect() {

window.location = "http://www.mypage.com/page1.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

and there is this link which opens in new window:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com/page2.php" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

any ideas on how i can achieve this?

Comment: The solution was already written in the "answers" section, but i wanted to point out on a error in your code. `window.onload = setTimeout(myRedirect, timeout);` does not ensure the whole page has been loaded. Basically, what are you doing here is: setting the timeout immediately when the browser processed your JS code, and then storing the timer id in the `windows.onload`. The correct implementation would be `window.onload = function() { setTimeout(myRedirect, timeout) };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store your timeout call in a variable.

```
var timeout = '5000';
var myTimeout;
window.onload = function(){
    myTimeout = setTimeout(myRedirect, timeout);
}
```

and when you want it cancelled, clear that timeout in that variable:

```
clearTimeout(myTimeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear the timeout when the link is clicked:

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="javascript:clearTimeout(t);">click here</a>
```

Note that the object 't' must be what is returned from the `setTimeout` function. So now that will look like:

```
var t;

window.onload = function() {
    t = setTimeout(myRedirect, timeout);
}
```

Also, I may point out here that what you are doing here is *generally* not recommended (there definitely are rules to this exception). It would be better to use HTTP headers for the redirect, but since I don't know what exactly your requirement is, I can't comment.

Comment: a `return false` statement would stop the link processing i.e. then not only will the timer be cleared, but also redirection due to clicking the link also will be cancelled.

Comment: Thanks @RohanPrabhu, I tried combining your and joseph's codes to come up with a solution but it seems i am missing something here. The page doesnt redirect anymore (considering i didnt click on the link)                                                                        <script>
        <!-- 
        var timeout = '5000';
        var myTimeout;
        window.onload = function(){
        myTimeout = setTimeout(myRedirect, timeout);
        }


        window.location = "http://www.mypage.com/page1.html";
        }
        //-->
        </script>

Comment: Shouldn't there be the myRedirect function? Looks like it isn't declared at all. The window.location = "wherever" should be enclosed within the myRedirect function.

Comment: @RohanPrabhu I got it now. Including  function myRedirect() { resolved the issue now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel your setTimeout by using clearTimeout, see example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)